# Fetch the Record ID of the Duplicated Row

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following Query:

```
$Query = "INSERT INTO table (name, bio) VALUES ('aname', `abio`)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
$last_id = $stmt->lastInsertId();

$Query = "INSERT INTO table2 (tid, papers) VALUES ($last_id, '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE papers = '2'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
```

`table` has the `aname, abio : unique`, and `table2` has `tid, papers : unique`

The user is supposed to `INSERT` a `name` and `bio`, If it is already exists or not, they insert the `papers` to the `table2` with the `id` of the inserted `name, bio`, The problem that if the `name, bio` already exists, I don't get the `$last_id`

How can I pull the `id` of the duplicated row When PDO tells me that that thre is a Dupicate?

Comment: I take it it tells you with an exception?, you can catch the exception and look it up by the unique field that failed in the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this

> How can I pull the id of the duplicated row When PDO tells me that that thre is a Dupicate

Means you have a unique field set on the table.

I would do something like this:

```
try{
    $Query = "INSERT INTO table (name, bio) VALUES ('aname', `abio`)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $last_id = $stmt->lastInsertId();
}catch(PDOExeption $e){
    if($e->getCode() != 23000){ //I think it's 23000
       //rethrow other PDO errors
        throw new PDOException(
           $e->getMessage(),
           $e->getCode(),
           $e
        );
    } 

    $Query = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'aname'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
    $stmt->execute();
    //fetch the first column (id) from the first row, which if its unique there will be only one.
    $last_id = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
}

$Query = "INSERT INTO table2 (tid, papers) VALUES ($last_id, '1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE papers = '2'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($Query);
$stmt->execute();
```

You may have to turn the error mode for PDO to exception if you haven't done so already.

```
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

But basically you catch the duplicate exception thrown by PDO, then you take the unique field, I'm using `name` because you didn't say what it was.  Then take the value that failed an look it up by that.  It stands to reason if you have a unique field and a value failed then the row you want has the same value.  Then you set `$last_id`. So last id get's set by lastInsertId or by the catch block.

P.S.  I didn't test any of this so sorry if there are any errors, but the theory is sound.

Comment: The key of the `table` is the `id` and it is `primary`, But as I understood,  I have to use another query to check up this existing row `id`, I really wonder why didn't they implement this functionality overall instead of having to run multiple queries for it.

Comment: You can do Insert Ignore, that ignores the errors and continues on.  So its more a separation of responsibility thing.  The insert is not really responsible for handling duplicate errors.